# Caliburn Micro - View & viewmodel in separate DLL

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I've been trying this for a while and i have some issues. I have a project which dynamically loads 1 or more DLLs and I can't get the view binding to work.

I've overridden the SelectAssemblies method as such:

```
 protected override IEnumerable<Assembly> SelectAssemblies()
    {
        string[] AppFolders = Directory.GetDirectories(Config.AppsFolder);

        List<Assembly> assemblies = new List<Assembly>();
        assemblies.Add(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        foreach (string f in AppFolders)
        {
            Assembly ass = Directory.GetFiles(f, "*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(Assembly.LoadFrom).SingleOrDefault();
            if (ass != null)
            {
                assemblies.Add(ass);
            }
        }
        Apps = assemblies;
        return assemblies;
    }
```

This works as intended, i then have a method which runs on a button click which does:

```
public void OpenApp(string appName)
    {
        //AppName should be the same as the dll.

        string assName = string.Format("TabletApp.{0}", appName);

        Assembly ass = AppBootstrapper.Apps.SingleOrDefault(x => x.GetAssemblyName() == assName);

        if (ass != null)
        {
            dynamic vm = ass.CreateInstance(string.Format("TabletApp.{0}.ViewModels.{0}ViewModel", appName));
            IoC.Get<IWindowManager>().ShowDialog(vm);
        }
    }
```

This finds the viewmodel fine, however i get the error "unable to find contract for 'ExampleView'" when i load ExampleViewModel. I've also had to add [Export(typeof(view)] for each view in the base assembly since I've made this changes. It appears that Caliburn micro has stopped initialising views automatically.

Anyone know what i've done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out i was doing nothing wrong, Along the way I've updated my caliburn.micro to 3.0.2. As it turns out a small change they made became a major breaking update. I wont go into it fully here other than to point out its the GetInstance in the bootstrapper that needs to be changed.

```
protected override object GetInstance(Type service, string key)
    {
        // Skip trying to instantiate views since MEF will throw an exception
        if (typeof(UIElement).IsAssignableFrom(service))
            return null;

        var contract = string.IsNullOrEmpty(key) ? AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(service) : key;
        var exports = container.GetExportedValues<object>(contract);

        if (exports.Any())
            return exports.First();

        throw new Exception(string.Format("Could not locate any instances of contract {0}.", contract));
    }
```

Please review the following link for more detailed information.

https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/pull/339